# How to get rows from a table with a column of uniques, dictated by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

It's difficult to explain so I made a sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table (a_id INT, number INT, other_data VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES 
(1, 2, "other text"),
(1, 3, "other text 2"),
(1, 4, "other text 3"),
(2, 5, "other text 4"),
(2, 6, "other text 5"),
(3, 7, "other text 6"),
(4, 8, "other text 7"),
(4, 4, "other text 8");
```

SQL Fiddle of the data - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a73d69/2

What I want to do is filter the table so that there are no duplicates in the `a_id` column.  As far as picking which specific rows to take, I want the ones where `number` is the greatest.  So in that example table, counting down from the top, it would be rows 3, 5, 6, and 7.

I've tried "GROUP BY" and "DISTINCT" but so far nothing is returning 100% correct.

Comment: Even when it's easy to explain , that's exactly what you should do. That said, this is the most frequently asked question under this tag

Comment: Also, always identify the PRIMARY KEY in your table definition

Answer (score 1):

This is a top-n-per-group problem. A common solution is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
rom sample_table s
where s.number = (select max(s1.number) from sample_table s1 where s1.a_id = s.a_id)
```

The subquery *correlates* with the outer query on `a_id`, and retains only the row(s) with the maxum `number` in each group of rows sharing the same `a_id`.

MySQL would take advantage of an  index on `(a_id, number)` to speed up the subquery, which would make a large difference on overall performance if your table has lots of rows.

Answer (score 1):

This would give you only one result for unique a_id and numbers, but there could be more that one row that cold fit  i added the GROUP_CONCAT, to see all other data

```
SELECT t1.a_id, t1.number, GROUP_CONCAT(other_data) 
FROM sample_table t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT a_id, MAX(number) maxn FROM sample_table GROUP BY a_id) t2
  ON t1.a_id = t2.a_id AND t2.maxn = t1.number 
GROUP BY t1.a_id, t1.number;
```

example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a73d69/6